# Dynamic obfuscation by self-modifying code

Tags: c, assembly, obfuscation

Here what's i am trying to do:

assume you have two fonction

```
void f1(int *v)
{
   *v = 55;
}
void f2(int *v)
{
   *v = 44;
}

char *template;
template = allocExecutablePages(...);

char *allocExecutablePages (int pages)
{
    template = (char *) valloc (getpagesize () * pages);
    if (mprotect (template, getpagesize (),
        PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC|PROT_WRITE) == -1) {
            perror (“mprotect”);
    }
}
```

I would like to do a comparison between f1 and f2 (so tell what is identical and what is not)  (so get the assembly lines of those function and make a line by line comparison)
And then put those line in my template.

Is there a way in C to do that?

THanks

### Update

Thank's for all you answers guys but maybe i haven't explained my need correctly.

basically I'm trying to write a little obfuscation method.
The idea consists in letting two or more functions share the same location in memory. A region of memory (which we will call a template) is set up containing some of the
machine code bytes from the functions, more specifically, the ones they all
have in common. Before a particular function is executed, an edit script is used
to patch the template with the necessary machine code bytes to create a
complete version of that function. When another function assigned to the same
template is about to be executed, the process repeats, this time with a
different edit script. To illustrate this, suppose you want to obfuscate a
program that contains two functions f1 and f2. The first one (f1) has the
following machine code bytes

```
Address Machine code
0          10
1          5
2          6
3          20
and the second one (f2) has
Address Machine code
0          10
1          9
2          3
3          20
At obfuscation time, one will replace f1 and f2 by the template
Address Machine code
0           10
1           ?
2           ? 
3           20
and by the two edit scripts e1 = {1 becomes 5, 2 becomes 6} and e2 = {1
becomes 9, 2 becomes 3}.


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef char * addr_t;

typedef struct {
uint32 offset;
char value;
} EDIT;

EDIT script1[200], script2[200];
char *template;
int template_len, script_len = 0;
typedef void(*FUN)(int *);
int val, state = 0;

void f1_stub ()
{
if (state != 1) {
patch (script1, script_len, template);
state = 1;
}
((FUN)template)(&val);
}

void f2_stub () {
if (state != 2) {
patch (script2, script_len, template);
state = 2;
}
((FUN)template)(&val);
}

int new_main (int argc, char **argv)
{
f1_stub ();
f2_stub ();
return 0;
}

void f1 (int *v) { *v = 99; }
void f2 (int *v) { *v = 42; }

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
int f1SIZE, f2SIZE;
/* makeCodeWritable (...); */
/* template = allocExecutablePages(...); */
/* Computed at obfuscation time */
diff ((addr_t)f1, f1SIZE,
(addr_t)f2, f2SIZE,
script1, script2,
&script_len,
template,
&template_len);
/* We hide the proper code */
memset (f1, 0, f1SIZE);
memset (f2, 0, f2SIZE);
return new_main (argc, argv);
}
```

So i need now to write the diff function. that will take the addresses of my two function and that will generate a template with the associated script.

So that is why i would like to compare bytes by bytes my two function

Sorry for my first post who was not very understandable!

Thank you

Comment: This question is incoherent and you will get better answers if you could explain your needs more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to do this at runtime or during authorship?

You can probably instruct your C compiler to produce assembly language output, for example gcc has the -S option which will produce output in file.s   Your compiler suite may also have a program like objdump which can decompile an object file or entire executable.  However, you generally want to leave optimizations up to a modern compiler rather than do it yourself.

At runtime the & operator can take the address of a function and you can read through it, though you have to be prepared for the possibility of encountering a branch instruction before anything interesting, so you actually have to programatically "understand" at least a subset of the instruction set.  What you will run into when reading function pointers will of course vary all over the place by machine, ABI, compiler, optimization flags, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Put the functions into `t1.c` and `t2.c` use `gcc -S` to generate assembly output:

```
gcc -S t1.c
gcc -S t2.c
```

Now compare `t1.s` and `t2.s`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there no other way to do it directly in the C file? (whitout building the 2 fonction separetly) ?

Comment: Just compile the single source file with -S, find the fragments that refer to the individual functions, and compare them.

Comment: You could call gcc on runtime and parse the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, go to

```
Project Properties -> Configuration -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Assembler output
```

or use compiler switches `/FA`, `/FAc`, `/FAs`, `/FAcs`. Lower-case `c` means output machine code, `s`-source code side-by-side with assembly code. And don't forget to disable compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Having read through some of the answers and the comments there, I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but maybe you're looking for a `gcc` invocation like the following:
`gcc -S -xc - -o -`

This tells gcc to input C code from stdin and output assembly to stdout.

If you use a vi-like editor, you can highlight the function body in visual mode and then run the command:
`:'<,'>!gcc -S -xc - -o - 2> /dev/null`
...and this will replace the function body with assembly (the "stderr > /dev/null" business is to skip errors about #include's).

You could otherwise use this invocation of gcc as part of a pipeline in a script.