# Copy function in memory

Tags: c, linux, assembly

I am attempting to hook a function of a linux program.
Basically searching unprotecting the function with mprotect and then putting a jmp inside the original function address re-directing to my function hook.

However I would like to copy the original function so I can call it when the modified function is not needed.
I would have a kind of hook like this

```
int CallHookedFunctionFoobar(int param1, int param2)
{
      if (g_somevariable)
           Foobar_original(param1, param2);
      else
           Foobar_modified(param1, param2);
}
```

So my question is... how could I know the size of a function, in bytes, so I could memcpy() it to a dynamically allocated buffer to execute it?

I thought about maybe embedding a small length disassembler and parse the opcode until I find the RETN optocode, but I'm unsure it would work in absolutely all cases (for example if more than one RETN resides in the same function :[)

Another reason because I want to do this is because the same function could have been hooked by another library..

Comment: Might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546071/copy-a-function-in-memory-and-execute-it

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if this is Linux-specific, then most probably your executable file is an `ELF` binary. So you can just parse the ELF header (using `libelf`, for example) to find/calculate the length of a function.

However, I don't see why you would need this. A simpler approach I can think of is patching the function on-the-fly, replacing its first few instructions with a `JMP` or `CALL` to the hook function meanwhile saving those overwritten instructions to patch it back later. Something like:

```
void call_hooked(void (*fn)(), unsigned char *ctx, size_t *n)
{
    unsigned char hook_patch[] = { 0x15, 0x20, 0x7f, 0x48 }; // I bluffed
    *n = sizeof(hook_patch);
    memcpy(ctx, fn, sizeof(hook_patch));
    memcpy(fn, hook_patch, sizeof(hook_patch));
    fn();
}

void call_orig(void (*fn)(), unsigned char *ctx, size_t n)
{
    memcpy(fn, ctx, n);
    fn();
}
```

Comment: Or, even easier — overwrite a PLT entry, of course if the symbol is not hidden.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Right, especially considering the fact that this is going to be used with dynamic libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
Indeed I could save the information inside an array and re-patch. Still, I do this mostly for learning purposes and thought I could go father.
Could you provide more informations on ELF parsing? seems very interesting. How would I check the function length in the ELF?
By sorting the syms offsets in the .symtab and the func offset from the next or...? Excuse my ignorance.
Could you provide some basic sample code? Thanks, 1 million times.

Comment: @Yannick [Libelf by example](http://people.freebsd.org/~jkoshy/download/libelf--/article.html)