# Illegal instruction error on simple ARM arbitrary code execution program

Tags: c, arm

I am writing a simple code execution exploit on a Raspberry Pi 3, and I am getting an "Illegal instruction" error. To compile this program, I have disabled ASLR and added the following compiler options:

```
-fno-inline -O0 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -Wall
```

I get a "assignment from incompatible pointer type" warning on the `g=h` assignment, but I don't see why that would be an issue.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void printFunction(char *f){
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        printf("\\x%x",(f)[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void f(){
    printf("Success\n");
}

int main(){

    void (*g)();

    g=f;
    printf("%p\n",g);
    g=(void *)0x1053c; // This is the address of f()
    printf("%p\n",g);

    char h[256];
    memcpy(h,f,256);

    printFunction((char *)g);
    printFunction((char *)h);

    g(); // Succeeds
    g=h;
    g(); // Fails
}
```

I use the `printFunction` function to see the memory that each pointer points toward. The memory pointed to by g and h are identical, but g points toward the text section, while h is somewhere on the stack, as expected. I understand that some memory is not executable, but the `-z execstack` flag should take care of that.

I've also considered that my problem could be related to alignment, but I have no idea how I would fix that.

Here is the disassembly of the relevant functions:

```
0001053c <f>:
   1053c:       e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
   10540:       e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
   10544:       e59f0008        ldr     r0, [pc, #8]    ; 10554 <f+0x18>
   10548:       ebffff88        bl      10370 <puts@plt>
   1054c:       e1a00000        nop                     ; (mov r0, r0)
   10550:       e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
   10554:       00010678        .word   0x00010678

00010558 <main>:
   10558:       e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
   1055c:       e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
   10560:       e24ddf42        sub     sp, sp, #264    ; 0x108
   10564:       e59f3084        ldr     r3, [pc, #132]  ; 105f0 <main+0x98>
   10568:       e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
   1056c:       e51b1008        ldr     r1, [fp, #-8]
   10570:       e59f007c        ldr     r0, [pc, #124]  ; 105f4 <main+0x9c>
   10574:       ebffff77        bl      10358 <printf@plt>
   10578:       e59f3078        ldr     r3, [pc, #120]  ; 105f8 <main+0xa0>
   1057c:       e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
   10580:       e51b1008        ldr     r1, [fp, #-8]
   10584:       e59f0068        ldr     r0, [pc, #104]  ; 105f4 <main+0x9c>
   10588:       ebffff72        bl      10358 <printf@plt>
   1058c:       e24b3f42        sub     r3, fp, #264    ; 0x108
   10590:       e3a02c01        mov     r2, #256        ; 0x100
   10594:       e59f1054        ldr     r1, [pc, #84]   ; 105f0 <main+0x98>
   10598:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
   1059c:       ebffff70        bl      10364 <memcpy@plt>
   105a0:       e51b0008        ldr     r0, [fp, #-8]
   105a4:       ebffffca        bl      104d4 <printFunction>
   105a8:       e24b3f42        sub     r3, fp, #264    ; 0x108
   105ac:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
   105b0:       ebffffc7        bl      104d4 <printFunction>
   105b4:       e24b3f42        sub     r3, fp, #264    ; 0x108
   105b8:       e1a02003        mov     r2, r3
   105bc:       e51b1008        ldr     r1, [fp, #-8]
   105c0:       e59f0034        ldr     r0, [pc, #52]   ; 105fc <main+0xa4>
   105c4:       ebffff63        bl      10358 <printf@plt>
   105c8:       e51b3008        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
   105cc:       e12fff33        blx     r3
   105d0:       e24b3f42        sub     r3, fp, #264    ; 0x108
   105d4:       e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
   105d8:       e51b3008        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
   105dc:       e12fff33        blx     r3
   105e0:       e3a03000        mov     r3, #0
   105e4:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
   105e8:       e24bd004        sub     sp, fp, #4
   105ec:       e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
   105f0:       0001053c        .word   0x0001053c
   105f4:       00010680        .word   0x00010680
   105f8:       0001053c        .word   0x0001053c
   105fc:       00010684        .word   0x00010684
```

Comment: Very dangerous subject, functions cannot be copied to diffrent place in memory. First reason is because code is store in .text section and you have access to stack and heap.
More about this you can find here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546071/copy-a-function-in-memory-and-execute-it

Comment: Writing shellcode into another process and then just calling that with, for example CreateRemoteThread on windows machines is a commonly used technique to execute shellcode. This specific case is very interesting, unfortunately my environment is very limited right now so i cannot even look at it in a debugger. What i did find out is the following though:

`memcpy(f,h,256);`

even though the memory seems to be the exact same, copying forth and back breaks the first `g` call, too.

at this point it seems to be fairly unlikely to be an alignment issue. maybe page protection / callingconv?

Comment: I don't know about ARM but on PowerPC it is not sufficient to just copy the code.  You also need to flush the caches and invalidate them so that the new code will get read correctly into the instruction cache.

Comment: nothing about this code is arbitrary nor expected in any way shape or form to work.  You might get lucky on some platforms not realizing it should fail.  But in general there is no reason to expect this code to work.  if it failed then you were successful.

Comment: In fact, are pages in which the stack is located even executable AT ALL?

Comment: What do you think `-z execstack` is for?

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a function into a data pointer of any type. The `memcpy(h,f,256);` is therefore illegal.

`g = h;` seems to compile because of the generosity of C but still results in a broken executable. `h` will be in a undefined state.