# Function pointer assignement and typecast

Tags: c, casting, function-pointers

I wanted to test a my idea about function pointers. I wrote a test but it doesn't work(causes a `Segmentation fault`). Here is my test simplified:

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
void a(){}
void b(){}
int main(){
    size_t s=0;
    char* p1=(char*)&a;
    char* p2=(char*)&b;
    while(*p1++==*p2++) s++;
    void (*o)();
    char* c=malloc(s);
    while(s--) *(c+s)=*((char*)&a+s);
    o=(void(*)())c;
    o();
    return 0;
}
```

The code should copy machine code of an empty function(here if finds the intersection of data at the addresses of two empty function and copies that) and run the copy.

Thanks for reaching out.

Comment: "*test a my idea*". What idea? What is that code supposed to do?

Comment: I am sorry. I first included it in the question by removed it afterwards. It should copy machine code(just RET in this case maybe) and run it.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73413685/edit) the post to update it with any info like that which is critical to understanding the question.

Comment: You should at least do some plausibility checks. For example, is `s > 0`? And why do you think you can run arbitrary machine code allocated in data memory? Did you hear about modern protection schemes?

Comment: When I wrote code to typecast a function pointer to a `char*`and entered it into a website to produce assembly from it, it was "like" the code of the function.

Comment: You want to copy code from a function into memory you've allocated on the heap. You should not expect that memory range to be executable. I would assume any recent operating system would not allow code execution from such a memory area.

Comment: Just to check, data at function pointer(as a address) is read-only (the part which stores the machine code)?

Comment: If you want to play around with stuff like this, I'd recommend getting some low end, von Neumann microcontroller board to play with. These allow you to wildly copy executable code to RAM and execute it from there. But if you use a Harvard one or a mid-range MCU with MMU, that's probably not an option.

Comment: I only heard of Texas Instruments doing von Neumann microcontrollers, as a side note. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few of the problems:

- Converting between object pointers and function pointers invokes undefined behavior so you have no guarantees that correct machine code will be generated for your program.
- You can't make any assumption of where these functions are allocated in memory.
- Using `char` for raw binary is always wrong, since it has implementation-defined signedness. Use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.
- Read accessing memory reserved for execution might cause a hardware exception from the MMU on most high end CPUs. And if not from the MMU then an exception from the OS. So what you are trying to do (copying a function's machine code to data RAM?) might not be possible.
- The malloc chunk you get might not have the same alignment requirements as a function, meaning that the address might not be suitable.
- `*(c+s) =`  is a fairly obvious array out of bounds bug. Don't write obscure loops that iterate downwards for no good reason. In this case simply use `memcpy`.
- When trying out your code on some x86_64 the functions a and b ends up as the raw binary `ret` instruction followed by a bunch of binary corresponding to the calling convention. More me, the functions stop having the same machine code before you reach the end of either of them. This is what the binary looks like:

[image]

But when I print the contents copied down to `c` (after fixing the other bugs mentioned in this answer) there's just 2 bytes holding C3 66, but as you can see from the pic that's in the middle of an instruction. I'm not great at decoding raw x86 asm, but the algorithm appears to be fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I came across the idea that function addresses should be aligned but totally forgot to check it. Sorry. Also is alignement there because instructions in some architerures seem to have same size in machine code like with arm64?

Comment: @markoj That's all very CPU specific and as a C programmer I tend not to care learning about it since the linker handles all that for me.

Comment: "malloc chunk you get might not have the same alignment requirements as a function," --> interesting!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica At least I wouldn't assume as much. I recall getting some very subtle function misalignment bug in a bootloader code on a Power PC and it was far from easy to track down.

Comment: I thought that `ret` is the only instruction that would be there, jumping the to the code on the address on the stack.

Comment: @markoj So did I but apparently not... and I don't know x86 64 well enough to tell what these are there for.

Comment: @Lundin, it seems that arm64 uses the `r14` register where I reffered to the stack(the address to jump to when `ret`) because it seems like the `bl` instruction is used for function calls(`putchar` for example).

Comment: Also, I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546071/copy-a-function-in-memory-and-execute-it. It shows how to make a memory page(I guess) able to be used for executing code from and also the `valloc` function.

Comment: Also, it seems like sometimes arguments are passed by register, not by putting on the stack.